# Kubuntu - adding a 3rd monitor connected to onboard

Tags: kubuntu, multiple-monitors

Please help me find the answer in adding a 3rd monitor. My setup is I have 2 monitors connected to an external VCard (GeForce GT 730). I am adding a 3rd monitor which is connected to the onboard video adapter.

Please advise what can be done for the 3rd monitor to be detected in this Kubuntu 15.10 (64Bit).

Thanks.

Comment: I've no idea what could be a problem, but at least plug in the third monitor, and execute either `xrandr -q` for Nouveau, or `nvidia-settings -q screens` for the proprietary one, then add the output to the post.

Comment: Hi, this is the output:
root@sumwhere:~# xrandr -q
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 2560 x 1024, maximum 16384 x 16384
DVI-I-0 connected primary 1280x1024+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 340mm x 270mm
   1280x1024     60.02*+  75.02  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    72.19    60.32  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    59.94

Comment: VGA-0 connected 1280x1024+1280+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 340mm x 270mm
   1280x1024     60.02*+  75.02  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    72.19    60.32  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    59.94  
DVI-I-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)

Comment: I mean that you have to edit the post to add it, because it is a needed information for anyone willing to help, plus comments doesn't save formatting. Okay, whatever, I see that xrandr indeed doesn't see the third monitor, that's weird. Does it connected with HDMI, right? Please, post also the output of `grep -e "EE\|WW" /var/log/Xorg.0.log`. Also, does the monitor work if it is the only connected monitor? If it does, does they work if you add more monitors?

Comment: Damn, I was inattentive. You're connecting the third monitor to a separate GPU. Unfortunately I don't know how does it work ☹ I found a [related thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/2ducnw/multimonitor_andor_multiple_gpu_on_linux/) on reddit btw. Looks like it is a problem specific to X11, and probably not present with Wayland.

Comment: Yep, I probably right about Wayland, you may [read here](https://www.phoronix.com/forums/forum/linux-graphics-x-org-drivers/wayland-display-server/819244-intel-continues-to-divest-in-wayland/page7?_=1461139359542) since the quote "Wayland support multi gpu". The only thing required is the Wayland support by drivers, and AFAIK NVidia added it recently into their proprietary ones.

Comment: Ok thanks. I will check in reddit. Sorry I can no longer edit the post that's why I have to put it on comment. Thanks again.